# Table within Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using a javascript product called prototip

Their default setup is the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
new Tip('test_style', 'Text for tooltip goes here', {
title: 'Title Goes Here',
style: 'protogrey'
});
</script>
```

I'm currently looking to add a table of sorts within my tooltip but for some reason when I add the table in to the text for the tooltip it will never display.

I have tried swapping the ' to " thinking it might be conflicting, I've also tried escaping the closing tags of the table to no avail. I just wanted to know with the current setup above if it would even be possible to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
new Tip('test_style', '<table><tr>
<td width="84">Test</td>
<td width="100">Test</td>
</tr></table>', {
title: 'Test',
style: 'protogrey'
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the newlines in the markup section? i.e. `<table><tr><td width="84">....`? JavaScript often has issues with strings going off to a new line.

Comment: JavaScript does not support multi-line string literals.

Comment: Hmm that is actually something that past my mind - Ill try that now

Comment: Worked perfectly /facepalm

Comment: you can also use the "\" character at the end of every line but the last, to keep using multiline strings.

Comment: @user2112337 You have any working demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to put the html into a sting and use multiple lines you have to escape the white space.

```
var html = '\
<h1>\
Hello\
</h1>';
```

Comment: But of course, this isn't part of the spec, so the fact browsers support it can't be assumed. From http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.4: "A 'LineTerminator' character cannot appear in a string literal, even if preceded by a backslash \."